# Internet Explorer 11 Compatibility Mode Missing

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

I used to set compatibility mode for Internet Explorer 10 like this:

1. Open Internet Explorer 10.
2. Press ‘Alt’ key on your keyboard to bring up the top menu. And then go to Tools > Developer Tools to bring up the IE developer tools.
3. Click ‘Browser Mode’ and then click on the Internet Explorer version to simulate.

With Windows 8.1 and Internet Explorer 11, those steps do not seem to work. How do I set compatibility mode in Internet Explorer 11?

Comment: You can add sites to a compatibility view list now, it's under Tools. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/use-compatibility-view#ie=ie-11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>F12</kbd> ---> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> ---> Emulation ---> Document mode